# Update instead of overwriting an Excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I am struggling with a big problem.

I am working to implement a program for a colleague. As he is good with Excel, he asked me to deal with NHL data. He has created an Excel file which may increase chances to win in 'NHL betting pools'. My function is to create a python program which will create/update Excel sheets with relevant data (e.g. player statistics, win - lose games, and so on).

To explain my problem, assume a simple Excel file with a 'data sheet' and a 'computation sheet'. The computation sheet use data from the data sheet.

How could I update data sheet without braking the computation? I had the choice to find a way to update the file or delete the file and recreate it, but the second option is likely to break the computation. Maybe the right way is to compare the old and the new data sheet and update it.

Is there a way to adapt my code so that it will update `Player statistics` sheet if it is not created?

Here is what I have done so far :

### pull_data.py

```
def send_request():
    # Request

    try:
        response = requests.get(
            url="https://api.mysportsfeeds.com/v1.1/pull/nhl/2017-2018-regular/cumulative_player_stats.csv", 
            params={
                "fordate": "20171009"
            },
            headers={
                "Authorization": "Basic " +
                     base64.b64encode('{}:{}'.format(USERNAME,PASSWORD)\
                                      .encode('utf-8')).decode('ascii')
            }
        )
        print('Response HTTP Status Code: {status_code}'.format(
            status_code=response.status_code))
        print('Response HTTP Response Body: {content}'.format(
            content=response.content))
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
        print('HTTP Request failed')

    return response
```

### create_and_update_xlsx_sheets.py

```
def player_statistics():
    """
    Add 'Player statistics' if the worksheet is not in file_name. 
    Otherwise, it will update the worksheet itself..
    """

    os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

    response = send_request().content
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(response.decode('utf-8')))
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name, engine='openpyxl')

    if os.path.exists(file_name):
        book = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_name)
        writer.book = book

    if 'Player statistics' in book.get_sheet_names():
        pass
    else: 
        df.to_excel(writer, 'Player statistics', index=False)


    writer.save()
    writer.close()


player_statistics()
```

In other words, by what could I replace `pass` in the following code in such a way it could work? Could I adapt it with http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pandas.html?

```
if 'Player statistics' in book.get_sheet_names():
    pass
else: 
    df.to_excel(writer, 'Player statistics', index=False)
```

### UPDATE

Be aware that this option is irrelevant, since it will break the computation. The sheet is deleted and created again, so it is well thought, but useless.

```
if os.path.exists(file_name):
    book = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_name)
    writer.book = book

if 'Player statistics' in book.get_sheet_names():
    std=book.get_sheet_by_name('Player statistics')
    book.remove_sheet(std)

df.to_excel(writer, 'Player statistics', index=False)

writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Comment: Same question, again?

Comment: No, it is the same question.

Comment: @J.Doe I think you will have a hard time getting an answer on this site. There is no one who will be able to answer this question, although it is relevant.